# Template argument deduction for references as arguments

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-argument-deduction

I am trying to profoundly understand Template Argument Deduction.
One point I am not understanding is, how I should apply the rules in the standard
[here](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.deduct.call#2.3) for the types `A` and `P`
for the following case (there is sadly no example on cppreference.com, see below the relevant section)

```cpp
template<typename T>
void foo(T t);

void call_with_reference(int& r) {
    foo(r)
}
```

- `P` is no [reference typ](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.deduct.call#2):
  which gives `P := T`
- `A := int&`

-> Match `P` and `A`  which gives: `T` is deduced to `int&`

which is cleary wrong. Where is the rule in the standard that says *references from `A` are removed*? A non-confusing, unambiguous clear answer would be very much appreciated.

**Relevant Section:**
[image]

Comment: How does P and A relate to the example? Maybe include the quote from the Standard in the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`A` is the type of an expression. Expression type is described by [[expr.type]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.type#1):

> If an expression initially has the type “reference to T” ([dcl.ref], [dcl.init.ref]), the type is adjusted to T.

So here `A` is `int`.

This expression is an `lvalue` but that will not play any role since `P` is not a reference.

Comment: Ah perfect, I didnt know that!